# EventStore - Corrupt database detected

Tags: c#, eventstoredb

I'm getting this error on 2 (out of 3) nodes in our EventStore cluster:

```
Corrupt database detected. ---> EventStore.Core.Exceptions.ChunkNotFoundException: E:\EventStore\data-EventStoreNode3\chunk-000000.000000 not found.
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at EventStore.Core.TransactionLog.Chunks.TFChunkDb.Open(Boolean verifyHash, Boolean readOnly) in C:\projects\eventstore\src\EventStore.Core\TransactionLog\Chunks\TFChunkDb.cs:line 76
   at EventStore.Core.ClusterVNode..ctor(TFChunkDb db, ClusterVNodeSettings vNodeSettings, IGossipSeedSource gossipSeedSource, InfoController infoController, ISubsystem[] subsystems) in C:\projects\eventstore\src\EventStore.Core\ClusterVNode.cs:line 165
   at EventStore.Core.VNodeBuilder.Build(IOptions options, IPersistentSubscriptionConsumerStrategyFactory[] consumerStrategies) in C:\projects\eventstore\src\EventStore.Core\VNodeBuilder.cs:line 1335
   at EventStore.ClusterNode.Program.Create(ClusterNodeOptions opts) in :line 0
   at EventStore.Core.ProgramBase`1.Run(String[] args) in C:\projects\eventstore\src\EventStore.Core\ProgramBase.cs:line 56
EventStore.Core.Exceptions.ChunkNotFoundException: E:\EventStore\data-EventStoreNode3\chunk-000000.000000 not found.
```

We have like literally no idea on why this is happening. Any help?

We are using 4.0.1, hotfix 4 version of ES

Maybe it will be misleading, but it seems that before that happened (like maybe a day before) we had some disk space errors and `OutOfMemoryException`s. Do you think it may be related?

Comment: Have you downloaded [the source code an checked what produces that error](https://github.com/EventStore/EventStore/blob/release-v4.0.4/src/EventStore.Core/TransactionLog/Chunks/TFChunkDb.cs)?  *literally no idea on why this is happening* the best placed person to debug this is you. Here's an exception that happens on one server, what's wrong isn't a very helpful question

Comment: I guess, I should also browse thru .NET platform source code if it starts giving me trouble and not ask about this problem on a board dedicated to helping people experiencing such problems? :) Exception stack trace is saying that ES is not able to find some chunk file and by browsing thru source code it looks like it's caused by ES not being able to update it's chunk cache (or whatever) before this happened. Why this happened, I don't know.